# unable to get JSON data from Restlet Client using Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, restlet, restlet-2.0

(I am totally new to Restlet client and Server scripting)

I am trying to get JSON Data from response body of the Restlet client using below code but I could not get that

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
  host: 'staging.api.pearson.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/sc-api/apis/content/urn:pearson:manifestation:db7eac5b-8f65-49dc-97bc-d0f5e824f135'
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);

  res.on("data", function(chunk) {
    console.log("BODY: " + chunk);
  });
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

**Getting the below output:**

[image]

But when using the Restlet client GUI, can able download the response BODY Json

[image]

Adding Environments details:

[image]

**Browser Snapshot:**

[image]

Kindly anybody suggest any way to do

(I am totally new to Restlet client and Server scripting)

Thanks

Comment: Looks like your working example uses https (port 443)

Comment: Thanks James, but got  response: 400 when using port 443

Comment: Status:  404     body:  {"fault":{"faultstring":"Unable to identify proxy for host: apipearsoncom and url:\/sc-api\/apis\/content\/urn:pearson:manifestation:db7eac5b-8f65-49dc-97bc-d0f5e824f135","detail":{"errorcode":"messaging.adaptors.http.flow.Applicati onNotFound"}}}

Comment: Yep that's what I get too.  So either the url is wrong or I'm not allowed to connect to that site.

Comment: Kindly check the GUI screenshot, just now its updated

Comment: The server is expecting to receive request headers as shown in your GUI screenshot.  Your code isn't setting any request headers.  You should edit the image that shows your APIkey and blank out that area.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145984/discussion-between-elambarathi-vimal-kannan-and-james).

Comment: Maybe you can compare the two requests using a tool like [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: Hi James, browser screenshot added, kindly check

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I see between your code and rest client GUI is the `port`. Is the host name a VIP? In that case, you shouldn't use port in your code.  Also as others said, use `https` as you are using It in GUI.

Comment: Thanks YuVI, I am not sure that this is VIP host, but Got response: 404 when took off Port

Answer (score 0):

As said in the first comment, your URL is only accessible via https

I myself use the [request.js](https://github.com/request/request) package

Example:

```
var request = require('request');
var url = 'https://staging.api.pearson.com/sc-api/apis/content/urn:pearson:manifestation:db7eac5b-8f65-49dc-97bc-d0f5e824f135';

request.get(url,{},function(err,res,body){
  if(err) 
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
  else {
    console.log("Status: ", res.statusCode);
    console.log("body: ", body);
  }
});
```

Comment: getting :  Status:  404     body:  {"fault":{"faultstring":"Unable to identify proxy for host: apipearsoncom and url:\/sc-api\/apis\/content\/urn:pearson:manifestation:db7eac5b-8f65-49dc-97bc-d0f5e824f135","detail":{"errorcode":"messaging.adaptors.http.flow.Applicati onNotFound"}}}

Comment: Kindly check the GUI screenshot, just now its updated